# How to mask only certain parts of a bitmap in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to be able to use the following image to mask other bitmap. So basically, I'm trying to get the mask image and replace it's black content with another bitmap. Like this for example:

[image: This is the mask]
[image: This is the final result]

I'm able to use this mask and create a round version of the original bitmap, but that does not retain that orange border around it. Any thoughts on how I can accomplish this effect? Thanks.

The code that I am using (that only creates a round image) is the following:

```
private static Bitmap applyMask(ImageView imageView, Bitmap mainImage) {
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas();

    Bitmap result result = Bitmap.createBitmap(50, 50, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);            

    canvas.setBitmap(result);
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    // resize image fills the whole canvas
    canvas.drawBitmap(mainImage, null, new Rect(0,  0, 50, 50), paint);

    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(sMaskImage, 0, 0, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(null);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: can you add the code you have used so far

Answer (score 1):

I use below code snipped to set masked images, this sample "bm" is my bitmap and "mMaskSource" is the resource id of mask object position in my drawable folder.

```
Bitmap mask = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), mMaskSource);
Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(mask.getWidth(), mask.getHeight(),
            Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas mCanvas = new Canvas(result);
Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, mask.getWidth(), mask.getHeight(),
            true);
mCanvas.drawBitmap(bm, 0, 0, null);
mCanvas.drawBitmap(mask, 0, 0, paint);
paint.setXfermode(null);
```

And finally you can use "result" bitmap object however you wish.

Comment: Thanks, but this will have the same result as my code above. It will result in a round image, not retaining the orange border contained in the mask.

Comment: My bad, i misunderstood i guess... But i also made something simillar, so i would suggest you to put two imageviews one has that orange circle, and second is your rounded image. Set their sizes as same, but put some padding inner one.